# Android starting a google maps intent from within a dialog

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, dialog, itemizedoverlay

I am using the google maps api with overlay items and want to be able to get directions when the user clicks these overlays.

I want this linked to the middle button of my dialog:

```
// Middle button
    dialog.setNeutralButton("Directions",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=20.344,34.34&daddr=20.5666,45.345"));
                    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
```

I get the following error "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}"

There are several answers to this on here but I cannot get any of them to work. I have tried both creating a constructor and calling getContext().

I am not sure if it is because my class is:

```
public class ItemizedOverlayLayoutActivity extends ItemizedOverlay {
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructer of your class `ItemizedOverlayLayoutActivity` add a parameter Context:

```
private Context context;
public MyItemizedNewOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    //...
    this.context = context;
}
```

just before you create your dialog add:

```
final Context fcontext = context;
```

Then in the dialog middle button use:

```
fcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

good luck